# how to show a popover on clicking a button in java fx

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make a popover when clicking a button in java fx, 
what is the best way to do this, can anyone say.

I already tried

```
Popup pop = new Popup
```

but this is not the one i actually need.

Comment: Had the same problem and didnt want to download external libraries like ControlsFX. here is the thread with the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622453/javafx-create-popover-without-external-libraries

Answer (score 3):

Use PopOver class which is part of [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/): http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/PopOver.html

Here is an example usage of it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21655844/5250273