# JavaFX create popover without external libraries

Tags: java, javafx

How can I create a popover like in the `DatePicker` class from `javafx.scene.control.DatePicker` as seen here:

[image]

The popover should when displayed be on top of all the other components as seen here (the popover is above the `TextField`):

[image]

Comment: Us a subclass of [`ComboBoxPopupControl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/ComboBoxPopupControl.html) as skin for your `ComboBoxBase` subclass or create & show a window yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a pretty simple solution to my problem, here is a code snippet in case people encounter the same problem

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane rootPane = new BorderPane();
        MenuButton openButton = new MenuButton("Open Context Menu");
        BorderPane contentPane = new BorderPane();
        CustomMenuItem item = new CustomMenuItem(contentPane);
        openButton.setStyle("-fx-selection-bar: transparent;"); //this is optional. it makes the blue background that appears when something is focused transparent
        contentPane.setPrefSize(300, 300);
        Label text = new Label("The ContextMenu will only close when you click the\nbutton below OR click outside of the ContextMenu.\nHow neat is that?");
        text.setStyle(" -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;"); //needs to bet set if you want the selection-bar to be transparent. if not set the text will become invisible
        contentPane.setTop(text);
        Button closeButton = new Button("Close this popover");
        closeButton.setOnAction(x -> {
            openButton.hide();
        });
        contentPane.setBottom(closeButton);
        item.setHideOnClick(false); // this will stop the ContextMenu from being hidden when clicking inside of it.
        openButton.getItems().add(item);
        rootPane.setCenter(openButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 550, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I just placed a `Pane` with all of my content inside of a `CustomMenuItem` and added that `CustomMenuItem` to my `MenuButton`.